# Multiline `ReplacementSpan` drawing issue

Tags: android, android-edittext, spannablestring

My custom replacement span works as long as text is not too long but as soon as text is longer than one line, span drawing completely breaks apart. My understanding is that `draw()` gets called twice in this case causing span to draw twice. There is no way to differentiate that second draw call from first one, giving you control over what to draw and where. `start` and `end` become useless as they report wrong values.

Is `ReplacementSpan` supposed to even work for multiline text? I would appreciate any help to resolve this issue.

[image]

This is what happens when I change selected text to my `CustomReplacementSpan`:

[image]

**CustomReplacementSpan.kt**

```
import android.graphics.Canvas
import android.graphics.Paint
import android.os.Build
import android.text.Layout
import android.text.StaticLayout
import android.text.TextPaint
import android.text.TextUtils
import android.text.style.ReplacementSpan
import androidx.core.graphics.withTranslation

class CustomReplacementSpan(val spanText: String, val color: Int) : ReplacementSpan() {

    override fun getSize(paint: Paint, text: CharSequence?, start: Int, end: Int, fm: Paint.FontMetricsInt?): Int {
        return paint.measureText(spanText).toInt()
    }

    override fun draw(
        canvas: Canvas,
        text: CharSequence?,
        start: Int,
        end: Int,
        x: Float,
        top: Int,
        y: Int,
        bottom: Int,
        paint: Paint
    ) {
        paint.color = color

        canvas.drawMultilineText(
            text = spanText,
            textPaint = paint as TextPaint,
            width = canvas.width,
            x = x,
            y = top.toFloat()
        )
    }


}

fun Canvas.drawMultilineText(
    text: CharSequence,
    textPaint: TextPaint,
    width: Int,
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
    start: Int = 0,
    end: Int = text.length,
    alignment: Layout.Alignment = Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
    spacingMult: Float = 1f,
    spacingAdd: Float = 0f,
    includePad: Boolean = true,
    ellipsizedWidth: Int = width,
    ellipsize: TextUtils.TruncateAt? = null
) {
    val staticLayout =
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(text, start, end, textPaint, width)
                .setAlignment(alignment)
                .setLineSpacing(spacingAdd, spacingMult)
                .setIncludePad(includePad)
                .setEllipsizedWidth(ellipsizedWidth)
                .setEllipsize(ellipsize)
                .build()
        } else {
            StaticLayout(
                text, start, end, textPaint, width, alignment,
                spacingMult, spacingAdd, includePad, ellipsize, ellipsizedWidth
            )
        }

    staticLayout.draw(this, x, y)
}

private fun StaticLayout.draw(canvas: Canvas, x: Float, y: Float) {
    canvas.withTranslation(x, y) {
        draw(this)
    }
}
```

**MainActivity.kt**

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.text.Spannable
import android.view.View
import android.widget.EditText
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat


class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    fun applySpan(view: View) {
        val editText = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.edit)
        if (editText.selectionStart < 0 || editText.selectionEnd < 0) {
            return
        }
        val fullText = editText.text
        val text = fullText.subSequence(editText.selectionStart, editText.selectionEnd)
        val span = CustomReplacementSpan(text.toString(), ContextCompat.getColor(this, android.R.color.holo_blue_dark))
        editText.text.setSpan(span, editText.selectionStart, editText.selectionEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)
    }
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/edit"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.EditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="applySpan"
        android:text="Make it span" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flowing onto a new line is, evidently, something that `ReplacementSpan` cannot do. Here is a quote from an article [Drawing a rounded corner background on text](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/drawing-a-rounded-corner-background-on-text-5a610a95af5) by Florina Muntenescu who blogs about spans and the like. (Emphasis in the following quote is mine.)

> We need to draw a drawable together with the text. We can implement a custom ReplacementSpan to draw the background and the text ourselves. **However ReplacementSpans cannot flow into the next line**, therefore we will not be able to support a multi-line background. They would rather look like Chip, the Material Design component, where every element must fit on a single line.

This is the issue that you are having. The article goes on about a possible solution that you may want to look into. For example, it may be possible to use some of the techniques outlined in the article to define multiple `ReplacementSpans` dependent upon line breaks like is done with the background drawables.

There are other span types that may be more congenial to your purposes. [Here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/style/package-summary) is  list of them.

Comment: That link was perfect! Just in case anyone wants to view the code that makes this all happen: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-text/tree/master/RoundedBackground-Kotlin