# Dotted underline position changed after changing orientation

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I have done the the multi line text support from below link
[Dotted underline TextView not wrapping to the next line using SpannableString in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220223/dotted-underline-textview-not-wrapping-to-the-next-line-using-spannablestring-in/58311184?noredirect=1#comment103134812_58311184)

After changing the orientation portrait to landscape dotted underline moved to other position

I have added 'android:configChanges="orientation"' in manifest for prevent on create call.

```
    <activity android:name=".Main2Activity"
        android:configChanges="orientation">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>


setAnnotation(
                spannableString,
                "production and conversion"
        )
```

Portrait:
[image]

Landscape:
[image]

Comment: You have to recalculate the position when the orientation is changed.

Comment: `android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize|keyboardHidden"`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to the original question you mention in this question and assuming that you are using the "DottedUnderlineSpan" from the original question, you will need to make the following changes:

The annotation spans are replaced with *ReplacementSpans* which must be explicitly recomputed ince you are handling orientation changes yourself. Once the annotation spans are set, do not remove them. They will remain valid across orientation changes.

The *ReplacementSpans* will, however, need to change. Upon orientation change, remove the replacement spans, allow layout to proceed and then recalculate the *ReplacementSpans* as shown in the following code and that should do it.

```
override fun onConfigurationChanged(newConfig: Configuration) {
    super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig)

    val textView1 = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView1)
    removeUnderlineSpans(textView1)
    textView1.viewTreeObserver.addOnPreDrawListener(
        object : ViewTreeObserver.OnPreDrawListener {
            override fun onPreDraw(): Boolean {
                textView1.viewTreeObserver.removeOnPreDrawListener(this)
                replaceAnnotations(textView1)
                return false
            }
        }
    )
}

private fun removeUnderlineSpans(textView: TextView) {
    val text = textView.text as Spannable
    val spans = text.getSpans(0, text.length, DottedUnderlineSpan::class.java)
    spans.forEach { span ->
        text.removeSpan(span)
    }
    textView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
}

private fun replaceAnnotations(textView: TextView) {
    val text = SpannableString(textView.text)
    val spans =
        text.getSpans(0, text.length, Annotation::class.java).filter { span ->
            span.key == ANNOTATION_FOR_UNDERLINE
        }
    if (spans.isNotEmpty()) {
        val layout = textView.layout
        spans.forEach { span ->
            replaceAnnotationSpan(text, span, layout)
        }
        textView.setText(text, TextView.BufferType.SPANNABLE)
    }
}
```